# nodejs how to get busy or locked file state?

Tags: node.js

```js
const states = fs.statSync(filePath)
```

I use statSync to get the status of the file, but got the error:

```bash
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'xxx'
```

I just want to get the file name, suffix, time and size. Not interested in file content.
If the file is being edited, time and size get the value before modification.
I just want to get the list of files without manipulating the files.

Is there any solution?
Thanks！